# implementing intermediate functions as coroutines or returning awaitables

Tags: python, python-asyncio

There are two ways to implement intermediate functions that sit between the creation of an `Awaitable` and the site where the object is `await`ed. One implementation makes the intermediate function a coroutine, where the `Awaitable` is `await`ed on; the user then `await`s on that coroutine. The alternative is to write the intermediate step as a function creating the `Awaitable` and returning it to the site where the `await` will happen. Below shows an example.

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Awaitable


async def wait1() -> None:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

def wait2() -> Awaitable[None]:
    return asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    await wait1()
    await wait2()

asyncio.run(main())
```

What are the differences between these two implementations? The pros and cons? Performance differences? Are there any behavioral differences? I am in the position of making a lot of these functions and want to do the "right" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As currently used, `wait1` and `wait2` are functionally equivalent. When called, both return a *coroutine object*, i.e. the result of running an async (coroutine) function. Differences arise if:

- the functions have side effects, and
- the awaitable they return is not awaited immediately

In that case, for `wait1` the side effect will occur only after it has been awaited, and for `wait2` it will occur as soon as it's called.

In most cases this makes no difference, but sometimes it can be observable. For example, the function `run_in_executor` can't be implemented as a coroutine because the current implementation is a function that first submits the received callable to the executor and then creates and returns an [asyncio future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) that proxies the underlying [concurrent future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future). This allows the API user to write:

```py
# I don't care about the result, just submit it
loop.run_in_executor(None, my_callback)
```

If `run_in_executor` were a coroutine, this would be no-op, nothing would get submitted until you either awaited it or passed it to `create_task` to get it run.

> I am in the position of making a lot of these functions and want to do the "right" thing.

I would use coroutines where possible, simply for clarity. It's ok to use the equivalence between `wait1` and `wait2` in places where you can't use coroutines, such as lambda expressions.